# PowerBI : dynamic dimension in chart : calculated column does not update when input parameter is modified in slicer

Tags: parameters, powerbi, calculated-columns

pbix file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x6u9a1vamiWnaTgJY-yYTIpANlz2FXyn/view?usp=sharing

I want to enable the user to do a simulation in PBI desktop. A color is associated to an ID depending on the risk score of the ID and a threshold the user can play with in the report. The user should be able to see how the amount of IDs per color changes depending on the threshold chosen.

**Screenshot of Data tab**

[image: Screenshot of Data tab]

**screenshot of report tab**

[image: screenshot of report tab]

I have tried using a calculated column, but as RADO pointed out, calculated columns cannot be impacted by filter changes, measures or parameters. I tried a measure which updates fine, but I cannot figure how to use this "color" measure as a axis in the plot I am trying to make.

Comment: You need to implement your calculation as a measure, not as a calculated column. Calculated columns don't react to user actions.

Comment: Thanks RADO, it works with a measure for the example I gave, but I actually want to build a dynamic dimension i.e a color associated with a score depending on a threshold. I have no clue how to do it with a measure. I have just edited the post to better reflect my need.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. It would be helpful if you post a picture of your data model, and explain how you plan to use this "dynamic dimension" (i.e., an example of a report using the dimension would be great to see).

Comment: I just updated the post to give you more info

Comment: Ok, I understand now what you want. Will post an answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small note first: I renamed your 'Table' into 'Data', since 'Table' is a reserved name; I also used my own names for the measures, change them as necessary.

Create a dimension table for score colors:

```
Score Colors = { "Red", "Green" }
```

(it's similar to the Threshold table - a disconnected table).

Create a measure for total amount:

```
Total Amount = SUM( Data[Amount] )
```

Create a measure that defines score color. A nuance: you should be careful about what you want to see in the totals. I chose not to show color in the totals as it makes no sense.

```
Score Color =
VAR Selected_Threshold = [Threshold Value]
VAR Current_Score = SELECTEDVALUE ( Data[Risk score] )
VAR Result = IF ( Current_Score > Selected_Threshold, "Green", "Red" )
RETURN
    IF ( NOT ISBLANK ( Current_Score ), Result )
```

Finally, create a measure that calculates score amount by color dynamically:

```
Dynamic Chart =
VAR Current_Color = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Score Colors'[Color] )
VAR Result =
    SUMX (
        VALUES ( Data[ID] ),
        IF ( [Score Color] = Current_Color, [Total Amount] )
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

How it works: we iterate over the list of IDs, compute their score colors, and compare to the color on the chart axis. If they match, amount is added to the result.

Finally, create a chart with Color field from the table "Score Colors" on x-axis, and [Dynamic Chart] measure on y-axis:

[image]

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it is very instructive

Comment: Hi RADO, say there is an additional date column and that may be diferent IDs on a same day. Any ideas about how to display the average amount by day instead of the sum in the above chart ? I guess I have to modify the measure "Total amount" and "Dynamic chart", but I could not figure out how. I can make a new post or provide sample data if you want.

Comment: Post a new question; upload a pbix file and provide an example of the desired outcome. Send me a link, I'll try to help.